# Handling 'groups' when running Poisson Regression in Python

Tags: regression, categorical-data, python, poisson-regression

Using Poisson Regression, I'm modeling `bids_received` (dependent variable) in my auctions website with features such as `city` (categorical), `item_category` (categorical), `asking_price` (continuous), `num_photos` (continuous) etc.

My overall aim is to find which features have the highest influence on bids received. This way, I can focus my energies on improving features that matter the most.

Here's how I try running the regression:

```
from statsmodels.genmod.generalized_estimating_equations import GEE
from statsmodels.genmod.cov_struct import (Exchangeable,
    Independence,Autoregressive) 
from statsmodels.genmod.families import Poisson

# 'df' is the dataframe containing all the data
f1 = "net_unique_bids ~ city1 + city2 + city3 + city4 + item_category1 + item_category2 + item_category3 + item_condition1 + item_condition2 + item_condition3 + asking_price + description_char_count + num_of_photos" 
model1 = GEE.from_formula(formula=f1, data=df, cov_struct=Independence(), family=Poisson())
```

This gives me an error like so:

> TypeError: from_formula() takes at least 4 arguments (3 given)

The error comes because the model's definition expects a `groups` parameter as well, which I haven't furnished:

```
def from_formula(cls, formula, groups, data, subset=None, 
                time=None, offset=None, exposure=None, *args, **kwargs)
```

What is `groups`? According to the docs:

> groups : array-like or string Array of grouping labels. If a string,
>   this is the name of a variable in data that contains the grouping
>   labels.

Even having read the definition of `groups`, I don't quite understand what to do here. What grouping labels is it expecting? Does it have something to do with the categorical variables? In which case, how does `f1` change (or will it at all)?

Please help clear this concept, ideally with an illustrative example using my scenario.

Comment: GEE is for clustered or longitudinal data and groups defines the cluster indices or cluster labels. If you don't have clustered or longitudinal data, then you can use GLM or Poisson.

Comment: @user333700: I do have categorical features - would that make my data clustered?

Comment: No, categorical features don't mean the data is clustered. Clustered in GEE means that observations within a cluster are correlated (e.g. if the same individual is observed several times) but uncorrelated across clusters.

Comment: @user333700: if you add these explanations as an answer, I'll accept it

Comment: In the modeling question above it would appear that the city variable could be considered a cluster id. Observations gathered from an individual city might well have  shared, unmeasured features affecting the propensity to buy at a particular price. In R the city id would be a single variable and might be entered as `+cluster(city_id)`. Stats.SE tends to shun questions that are focused on implementations in a single computer language, so this might have received more attention on StackOverflow if it included a workable example for testing and demonstration.